# required standards for US domestic foreign language education

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, multiple-languages, teaching, teaching-methods

In reference to [my earlier post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17306/sources-on-average-retention-rate-of-language-based-on-time), I'm going to be teaching foreign languages in some capacity and was advised by a board of education that I ought to understand and incorporate foreign language edu. standards into my curriculum. They only named ACTFL, but obviously there are many more.

I've recently gone through the ACTFL standards, and read through the [World Readiness Standards](https://www.actfl.org/publications/all/world-readiness-standards-learning-languages) (WRS) document, along with the WRS for Chinese and Spanish specifically. [Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/k12/education-standards) seems to adhere to 6 standards, both foreign and domestic. DuoLingo seems to measure against performance on the [WebCape Exam](http://www.perpetualworks.com/webcape/overview) ([Source](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/186923)), while they [loosely state that their users achieve Common Euro Framework A2 level](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/1980768) after completing their learning tree.

If I'm focused first on domestic US audience, should I still understand foreign standards like [Common Euro Framework of Reference](http://www.coe.int/t/dg4/linguistic/cadre1_en.asp)? Across the curricula I've seen (local edu. institutions and software alike), there doesn't seem to be a common standard adherence. If not, can I assume ACTFL is the de facto domestic standard to follow for K-12 students? I haven't seen any of these curricula adhere much to AP standards.

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Is there anything you have learnt about this in the last 6 months and that you could post as an answer? (It is perfectly OK to answer your own questions.)